# can't remove permissions on folder with powershell

Tags: powershell, acl

I'm using powershell to remove folder permissions. My code is something like this

```
$folder = "\\myServer\C$\myFolder";
$folder_acl = Get-Acl $folder;
$permission_toDelete = $folder_acl.Access | where{  <# selection operation #> }
$permission_toDelete | Foreach-Object { $folder_acl.RemoveAccessRule($_) }
```

This code return a lot of `True`, but it actually doesn't change permissions. The user I'm using is administrator on that server.
I also tried to remove inheritance with this piece of code `$folder_acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $false);` but still have the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that left is to pipe the current acl (after removal) to the `Set-Acl` cmdlet:

```
$folder_acl | Set-Acl
```

All True output is the return value of each removed acl. You can suppress it if you want:

```
$folder_acl.RemoveAccessRule($_) | Out-Null
```

Comment: Many thanks!
I was missing that each operation in `$folder_acl` must be committed using `Set-Acl $folder $folder_acl`